# C# Streaming from IP Camera and save to file in UWP Windows 10

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, camera, uwp, vlc

I am developing an universal windows 10 App that must record from an ACTi ip camera, and recording to file. For the preview i used VLC.MediaElement and it works perfectly, but i need to record or save this continuous frames to video file. Anyone knows how saving it to file. Cameras streams using http protocol, not RTSP or anything else.

it doesnt mind if I use VLC of FFMPEG, but I can´t launch it from cmd.exe in UWP apps.

any ideas?.

I used VLC.MediaElement this way. For the Preview there is no problem:

```
 <vlc:MediaElement Name="VLCPreview" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" HardwareAcceleration="True" AutoPlay="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="960" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1141" Margin="299,0,0,0">
            <vlc:MediaElement.TransportControls>
                <vlc:MediaTransportControls ControlPanelOpacity="0.8" />
            </vlc:MediaElement.TransportControls>
        </vlc:MediaElement>
        <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" AutoPlay="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="204" Margin="38,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212"/>
```

But I think I can´t recod using it becausa probably is under developing.

My idea is creating something like that, but it doesnt work streaming continuously, just the first frame.

```
  public async void StartRecording()
    {
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        Debug.WriteLine(storageFolder.Path);   

        Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFileVid =
await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "File.avi",
Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists)



VLCPreview.Source = "http://Admin:123456@192.168.0.21:6021/cgi-bin/cmd/encoder?GET_STREAM";




        try
        {
                            HttpClientHandler aHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                            aHandler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Admin", "123456");
                            aHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;

                            HttpClient aClient = new HttpClient(aHandler);
                            aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;

                            HttpResponseMessage response = await aClient.GetAsync("http://192.168.0.21:6021/cgi-bin/cmd/encoder?GET_STREAM", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);//urlLinkToOnlineStream


                            var destinationFile = sampleFileVid;
                            var fileStream = await destinationFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

                            Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                             IInputStream inputStream = stream.AsInputStream();
                             ulong totalBytesRead = 0;
                             while (true)
                             {
                                 // Read from the web.
                                 IBuffer buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(1024);
                                 buffer = await inputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, buffer.Capacity, InputStreamOptions.None);
                                 if (buffer.Length == 0)
                                 {
                                     break;
                                 }
                                 totalBytesRead += buffer.Length;
                                 await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer);
                                Debug.WriteLine("TotalBytesRead: {0:f}", totalBytesRead);
                            }

                            inputStream.Dispose();

                            fileStream.Dispose();  

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Excepción de vídeo en StartRecording: ", ex);
        }
    }
```

I am trying to follow 3 strategies:

1. Record using appropiate c# code.
2. Launche vlc.exe or ffmpeg.exe (desktop apps) from my uwp app.
3. Using VLC.MediaElement to record.

I'd rather first or second option in order to manage correctly the resources of the computer, but there is no problem if it works, just custom the buffers.

Thanks in advance, remember it is an ip camera, not webcams, I can´t use captureElement.

Comment: Could you please provide some code snippet about how you get the Camera streams currently?  It will be much better if you can also provide some code you using VLC.MediaElement for preview.

Comment: Edited with the code i did.

Comment: I tested your code, it can download the video to the local folder successfully. What issue you met with the above code snippet?

Comment: Can you play the video file that it creates?. I Can´t. Other thing is how to stop recording, any ideas?. It is oriented to record long videos. would be correct using these strategy?. Thanks for your help!